# Can't save an image using ipywidgets in jupyter notebooks / Voila

Tags: python, file-upload, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets, voila

I'm trying to make a web application in jupyter notebook using voila but it's my first time and I can't get it to work.

My goal is to upload an image, save it to a predefined folder and display it in the app.

So far, i can create the upload widget like this:

```
import ipywidgets as ipw

uploader = ipw.FileUpload()
display(uploader)
```

and it's ok, but when i want to acces the value or content to save it, i get this error:

```
uploader.value
```

{}

```
uploader.content
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [21], in <cell line: 1>()

----> 1 uploader.content

AttributeError: 'FileUpload' object has no attribute 'content'
```

Any help or recommendation will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to observe the change upon file upload. An example will probably illustrate it best.

To see it in operation go [here](https://github.com/fomightez/3Dscatter_plot-binder) and press '`launch binder`'. When the sessions spins up, select 'streamlined 3D scatter plot in Voila interface' from the list of available demonstrations.

Based on [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/binder-configuration-for-large-ipywidget-file-upload/4662/2?u=fomightez).

The code for that is [here](https://nbviewer.org/github/fomightez/3Dscatter_plot-binder/blob/master/3D_scatter_Voila_matplotlibSTREAMLINED.ipynb).

There is equivalent of that running in the notebook if you choose '3D scatter plot using data in a file and Voila interface' from the list of available demonstrations.

---

Based on [here](https://nikvdp.com/post/jupyter-uploads/) the way you are approaching it, it seems:

> "Once the user has picked a file with the file selector, the contents of the file will be available in a bytes object, under the .data property of the FileUpload object." - [SOURCE](https://nikvdp.com/post/jupyter-uploads/)

Maybe you can try accessing that?

See also https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20List.html#file-upload